# How to use the buzzer instead the bell sound

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, teminal-bell

I've been looking for a while and I couldn't find what I need.

My goal is to write some shell scripts to play songs using the `beep` command (that means that I really want that old-fashioned buzz).

I've installed the `beep` program, loaded the module using `modprobe pcspkr`, commented the `blacklist pcspkr` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, and used `alsamixer` to unmute the beep sound.

Nevertheless, it still didn't work. I found out by running `echo -e '\a'` that the OS (Ubuntu MATE 18.04) is using some fancy `.ogg` sound.

So, my question is: what do I have to do to have my beloved `beep` working as it should?